# SQL statement syntax error

Tags: java, sql, syntax

Having trouble with an sql statement to retrieve a record between two timestamps. This is just giving me a NullPointerException and I think it's just a syntax error, II've been searching around and I couldn't find anything. This is the statement:

```
private static final String strGetRecordByDate =
    "SELECT * FROM APP.MYTABLE " +
    "WHERE MYDATE >= ?, AND MYDATE <= ? " +
    "VALUES (?, ?)";
```

creating the statement:

```
stmtGetRecordByDate = dbConnection.prepareStatement(strGetRecordByDate);
```

The nullpointer exception shows on stmtGetRecordByDate.clearParameters():

```
public Vector getRecordByDate(Date datefrom, Date dateto){
    Vector<String> records = new Vector<String>();
    ResultSet results = null;
    java.sql.Date sqlDatefrom = new java.sql.Date(datefrom.getTime());
    java.sql.Date sqlDateto = new java.sql.Date(dateto.getTime());
    try {           
        stmtGetRecordByDate.clearParameters();
        stmtGetRecordByDate.setDate(1, sqlDatefrom);
        stmtGetRecordByDate.setDate(2, sqlDateto);
        results = stmtGetRecordByDate.executeQuery();
        while (results.next()) {
            int id = results.getInt(1);
            String entry = results.getString(2);
            records.add(entry);
        }
    } catch(SQLException sqle) {
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }
    return records;
}
```

The Rest of the queries and statements work fine so I know that the database itself is fine there is just something wrong with this one.

Any suggestions would be great.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a `VALUES` in that context and you have a stray comma in your WHERE clause; you want this:

```
private static final String strGetRecordByDate =
        "SELECT * FROM APP.MYTABLE " +
        "WHERE MYDATE >= ? AND MYDATE <= ?";
```

You could also use `BETWEEN`:

```
private static final String strGetRecordByDate =
        "SELECT * FROM APP.MYTABLE " +
        "WHERE MYDATE BETWEEN ? AND ?";
```

but that's just a matter of style.

I'm not certain about the Java side of things but you're probably getting a `null` in `stmtGetRecordByDate` because of your invalid SQL.

Comment: Haha yeah sorry the stray , wasn't in the code just a misstype. WHERE BETWEEN worked perfectly thanks

Comment: How Can I use parameters if I can't use VALUES?

Comment: @stroduces: Your `stmtGetRecordByDate.setDate` calls bind values to the placeholders. `VALUES` is usually only used with an INSERT.

Comment: Strange, it's not giving errors anymore but the output Vector is always empty but I know that there should be values there. Hmmmm. Well your statements are right I think there's just flaws in my code. THanks!

Comment: @stroduces To add to what @mu has already mentioned, using `values()` with a SELECT statement is syntactically incorrect. The '?' in your SELECT statement is what is used to set values to the parameters in your `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: @IceMan: Some databases will let you use VALUES in a FROM; PostgreSQL, for example, is happy with `select * from (values (1), (2)) as dt`.